# Prove the following r-step transition

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X_0, X_1, X_2,...$ be a Markov Chain on state space $S=\{1, 2,..., n\}$

and let $P$ be the Transition Matrix of the above Markov chain

Prove that

$\Bbb{P}(X_{t+2}=j|X_t=i) = (P^2)_{ij} $

for all $1\le{i, j}\le{n}$, and $t=0,1,2,3,...$

I know that that 
$P^2=\begin{pmatrix}
        p^{(2)}_{11} & p^{(2)}_{12} & \cdots& p^{(2)}_{1n} \\
        p^{(2)}_{21} & p^{(2)}_{22} & \cdots& p^{(2)}_{2n} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
p^{(2)}_{n1} & p^{(2)}_{n2} & \cdots& p^{(2)}_{nn} \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

But I am unsure how to complete the proof

The Definition of a Markov Chain is as follows:

A Stohastic Process $X_0,X_1,...$ on a statespace S is a Markov Chain if for all $t\in{\Bbb{N}}$ satisfies

$\Bbb{P}(X_{t}=s|X_{t-1}=s_t,X_{t-2}=s_{t-1},..,X_0=s_0) = \Bbb{P}(X_{t}=s|X_{t-1}=s_t)$

for all $s,s_t,s_{t-1},...,s_0\in{S}$ for which the conditional probabilities are defined

Comment: Which definition of "Markov chain" do you use/know?

Comment: I have have added the definition to the question above

Comment: Well, if you define it this way, then what's the relation between the Markov chain and the matrix $P$?

Answer (score 0):

Conditioning on the value of $X_{t+1}$, we have, for any $i,j$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_{t+2}=j\mid X_t=i) &=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} P(X_{t+2}=j\mid X_{t+1}=k,X_t=i) P(X_{t+1}=k\mid X_t=i) \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} P(X_{t+2}=j\mid X_{t+1}=k) P(X_{t+1}=k\mid X_t=i) \qquad\text{by the Markov property} \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} p_{kj}p_{ik} \\
&=& (P^2)_{ij}.
\end{eqnarray*}